# Create an SRT file from mp3 + text

Tags: nlp, speech-recognition

TL;DR: what approach would you take to match an existing text file into a mp3, generating an SRT file?

The situation is this:

- I have people reading over text word by word
- They upload the mp3 files into our system
- Then the mp3 shall have SRT files so we can highlight the text when the voice is played over it.

I know there are some speech recognition software out there (with still mediocre results), but this is a bit different: we only need to somehow match what we already have.

How would you approach this problem? Any idea?

Cheers from Sai Gon, Vietnam
Till

P.S. I started using Stackoverflow a couple of years ago but just had to create a new account linked to my Google account.

Comment: This is called speech alignment (or text-to-speech alignment, or forced speech alignment). There are tools out there if you look. It's an area of active research, so they might or might not be good enough for your use.

Comment: Thanks @hobbs - this is helpful! Now I can dig a bit into that. Merry xmas!